# How to create double line text in ActionBar like new GMail app

Tags: android, gmail, android-actionbar

Google release the new gmail app for Android, and I noticed they display both "Inbox" and the user's email in the same spot.

Is this a standard ActionBar feature that I can duplicate in my app?

How can I create a double line text with different fonts in the ActionBar, or can I create a custom Widget and use it in the ActionBar?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default ActionBar has a title and sub-title: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSubtitle(int)

Please note that `DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE` needs to be set.

Comment: how to set onclicklistner for title and subtitle of action bar